# Raspberry pi- obtain details of sensor connected

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, sensors

Components:-
Raspverry pi 3,
Temperature sensor DS18B20,
LCD display screen.

I am trying to create a simple program that gets the sensor values and shows the output on display screen connected to rpi.
But, I require some more information of the sensor such as 'manufacturer details, model number, type of sensor, etc.'  Is there a way to get these details?
I want the details to be shown as soon as the sensor is connected to rpi.
 Please help!

Comment: Without knowing what sensor this is, it would be impossible for anyone to answer this on stack overflow, right? I would suggest editing or deleting this question ASAP before you get downvoted to oblivion

Comment: @jeanluc edit my question

Comment: DS18B20 does not provide such info upon connection.